# GP problem to calculate sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to form a $f(n)$ to calculate the sum of n-terms of the progression $5, 55, 555, 5555, ...$

My attempt:

$$5+55+555+5555+...=\frac{5}{9}(9+99+999+9999+...)=\frac{5}{9}((10-1)+(10^{2}-1)+...+(10^n-1))$$

But I am not sure how to proceed from here. I know that this is related to GP. A major help would be identifying the common ratio here.

Comment: You are on the right track. The formula for the sum of a geometric series is $$1+q+q^2+\cdots + q^n=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$$ for $q\ne 1$, which you can use to finish the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. $$\frac{5}{9}((10-1)+(10^{2}-1)+...+(10^n-1))=\frac{5}{9}((10+10^2+...+10^n)-n)$$ Now it's easy to calculate the common ratio for $10+10^2+...+10^n$ as Peter suggested. $$\frac{50}{81}(10^n-1)-\frac{5n}{9}$$ In general, for the series $m+\overline{mm}+\overline{mmm}+\overline{mmmm}+...$, the sum is $$\frac{10m}{81}(10^n-1)-\frac{mn}{9}$$

Comment: $m \in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}$